# How do I fix (TypeError: must be a real number, not a tuple) error that I get when I run this code?

Tags: python

```
from scipy.integrate import simps
import math as m

#5
dx = ((m.pi/2)-0)/100
x = (0, (m.pi/2) + dx, dx)
t1 = m.sqrt(x)
t2 = m.sin(x)
y = t1 * t2
calc = simps(y,x)
print("The approximation with Simpson's Rule for 100 subintervals is", calc)
```

This is the integral I'm trying to solve using Simpsons Method:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DUky.png

Comment: Can you provide the whole error, such as where it occured

Comment: You might need to look into np.sqrt(x)*np.sin(x) as we are dividing the linespace into 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your x is not a range but a tuple with 3 elements and you can't sqrt a tuple

```
   x = (0, (m.pi/2) + dx, dx)
```

Maybe just like that:

```
from scipy.integrate import simps
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,np.pi/2,100)
t1 = np.sqrt(x)
t2 = np.sin(x)
y = t1 * t2
calc = simps(y,x)
print("The approximation with Simpson's Rule for 100 subintervals is", calc)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using numpy you can do it as following. Note that here I am using the 1/3 approximation of Simpson's rule. You can refer numpy
[documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to get some insights about using line space.

```
import numpy as np

def simpsonsTheorem(fn, a, b, n):
    x = np.linspace(a, b, n + 1)
    w = 2 * np.ones(n + 1)
    w[0] = 1.0
    w[-1] = 1
    for i in range(len(w)):
        if i % 2 == 1:
            w[i] = 4
    width = x[1] - x[0]
    area = 0.333 * width * np.sum(w * fn(x))
    return area


def f(x):
    return np.sqrt(x)*np.sin(x)


a = 0
b = np.pi/2

approxIntegral = simpsonsTheorem(f, a, b, 100)
print(approxIntegral)
```

As you are defining the function for interval of size 100 its better to use the numpy functions instead of math functions.It will provide an output

```
0.9764744073654472
```

If you want to to do it in your method you can do it like below.

```
from scipy.integrate import simps
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,np.pi/2,101)
y = np.sqrt(x)*np.sin(x)
calc = simps(y,x)
print("The approximation with Simpson's Rule for 100 subintervals is", calc)
```

The output will be like below.

```
The approximation with Simpson's Rule for 100 subintervals is 0.9774518592246717
```

There is a slight deviation in both answers as the first one is using 1/3 approximation but the scipy might use 3/8 approximation.